# using filter to filter objects in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am testing out $filter function, i haven't worked with it, can somebody tell whats the problem, why it inst filtering the objects.

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8nDQ/33/)

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function ctrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.images = [{
        orgName: 'B',
        sortOrder: 111
    }, {
        orgName: 'A',
        sortOrder: 12
    }, {
        orgName: 'D',
        sortOrder: 13
    }, {
        orgName: 'C',
        sortOrder: 14
    }];

    $scope.filter = function () {
        $scope.images = $filter('filter')($scope.images, 'orgName');
    }
}
```

Comment: what exactly you're trying to do? to sort them by `orgName` ?

Comment: no to filter them, if a click on A it should return only A and so on

Comment: like this: http://jsfiddle.net/M8nDQ/38/ ?

Comment: kind a yes. Is it possible, that my list, isn't filtering too? So only the real data is filtering not the list ?

Comment: Of course: http://jsfiddle.net/M8nDQ/47/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8nDQ/56/)

I also changed the HTML, the links is now (pass the orgName as an argument):

```
<a href="" ng-click="filter(image.orgName)">{{image.orgName}}</a>
```

Now the filter gets the orgname as an argument and has a function to compare:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
function ctrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.images = [{
        orgName: 'B',
        sortOrder: 111
    }, {
        orgName: 'A',
        sortOrder: 12
    }, {
        orgName: 'D',
        sortOrder: 13
    }, {
        orgName: 'C',
        sortOrder: 14
    }];

    $scope.filter = function (orgName) {
        $scope.images = $filter('filter')($scope.images, {'orgName': orgName});
    }
}
```

You may want to consider to have two list of the list or once you filter you lost all the other elements for ever. Something like displayImages, allImages, for example.

Another [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/M8nDQ/57/) with two list as I said above ans a reset.

Comment: Yes i know that i loose info. If i use select , and i dont choose a filtering value, it should reset filter to default, so it shows all the values, what should i add ?